# Eclipse Source not found, когда хочу посмотреть исходники

Tags: java, eclipse

Когда хочу посмотреть исходный код в JDK, например что бы посмотреть, как работает java.util.HashMap
Нажимаю Ctrl + кликаю на соответствующий класс, и мне выкидывает 
Class file editor
Source not found[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с этим бороться ?

Comment: Предположу что исходников действительно нет и их надо добыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кликайте на `Change Attached Source`, в появимшемся окне кликайте `External Location` - `External File` и выбирайте `src.zip`.  `src.zip` должен находиться c:/program files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/ (судя по картинке)

Comment: Делал так, но по глупости своей я изначально JDK установил не в 
 c:/program files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45 ((
Исправил это дело и все работает.
Спасибо)